# Do we have "he'sa", "they'ra", "we'ra", "you'ra" slang as we got with "I'ma"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

ok, [I'ma=I am going to](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/i'ma)

Ex: *I'ma kill you=I'm going to kill you*

My question is:

Do we have "**he'sa**", "**they'ra**", "**we'ra**", "**you'ra**" slang as we got with "I'ma"?

Ex:

**he'sa*= he's going to

**they'ra**=they're going to

**we'ra**=we're going to

**you'ra**=you're going to

Comment: You mean, for example, **He'sa kill you**?  I've never heard it, but there are many kinds of slang, so I guess it's possible.

Comment: [Southeastern US] I have heard phrases close to this, but only paired with "gonna". "We're a-gonna go down to the store". Since "gonna" is "going to", I don't think this is a "we'ra" meaning "we're going to". The extra 'a' here (pronounced, never written) doesn't seem to have any meaning.

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of learning English, you should avoid this kind of slang entirely.  These examples are not words, but a representation of a regional accent.  It is difficult to use a regional accent correctly, and you should really learn it directly from the people who use it.  Getting an accent wrong makes you look foolish or deceitful.

I know of two ways to use the "I'm ~a" phrase.

First, understand that you can shorten "I'm going to go." to "I'm gonna go.", and in some places, further to "I'm ~a go."  The meaning of this is pretty clear through context, and the usage is common in some communities, but it's not "proper" English.  I've used it myself on many occasions.

The other use is to emphasize a following verb, and make it more immediate. For instance, "I'm coming" vs "I'm a-coming".  (*Folsom Prison Blues*, for instance, talks about a train a-comin'.) This accent is closely associated with the South or "Country".

Your examples of "He's ~a", "She's ~a", etc would make sense with the second usage, where they modify the following verb, but the first usage (as a shortened version of "going to") would confuse a native speaker.

Answer (score -1):

I've never seen it written that way, but

> he'sa = he is a
>   He'sa bad dude.

BTW, your

> I'ma

is usually pronounced in northern AmE urban slang

> I'mo = I am going to
>   *I'mo kick your butt.*

It's similar to

> gonna = going to
>   wanna = want to
>   shoulda = should have
>   coulda = could have

You might be able to combine them to create a regional accent

> He'sa gonna kill you.
>   *He is going to kill you*